# .NET MAUI app crashing because it's not loading image file

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI app, I changed the icons used by the app from font based icons to `PNG` files and I store these images in `Resources > Images` folder.

I was able to successfully create a package and upload it to TestFlight but when I try to open the app, it crashes immediately. In crash logs, I see that the cause of crash is that the app was unable to load the `PNG` file I use for the `Flyout` i.e. the hamburger menu icon.

The other key change in the app is that it's now a .NET 7 based app.

I thought the publish process would add the `PNG` images used by the app to the `ipa` package if I placed them in `Resources > Images` folder.

Any idea what could be the issue here?

Here are screenshots of exception logs

[image]

[image]

And here's the MyApp.csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>MyApp</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>MyApp</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.mycompany.myapp</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>0636ab8b-e4f3-4c11-83e5-b809594a10b5</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.2</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>68</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net7.0-ios'">
      <CodesignKey>Apple Development: Samuel Uresin (3YQ4LF4U5J)</CodesignKey>
      <CodesignProvision>VS: llc.iquest.ingrid.connect Development</CodesignProvision>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.png" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.png" Color="#262627" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\about_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\badge_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\biz_profile_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\coupons_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\customers_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\dashboard_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\feed_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\hamburger_manu_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\intercom_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\plus_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\power_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\qr_scan_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\qr_scan_large_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\search_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\settings_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\shop_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\single_user_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\subscriptions_graphite.png" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\user_profile_graphite.png" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.14.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Ingrid.Aurora" Version="1.5.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Ingrid.Core" Version="1.5.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="MonkeyCache.FileStore" Version="1.6.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Plugin.InAppBilling" Version="6.7.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Maui.Audio" Version="0.1.0-preview1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Sentry.Maui" Version="3.23.1-preview.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Maui.Barcode" Version="20.3.56" />
        <PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls" Version="0.2.0-preview.2" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.8.116" />
        <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.core" Version="2.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl" Version="2.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.sqlite3" Version="2.1.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I guess when you debug your application is not crashing? or you see the same exception in the log?

Comment: When I run the app in simulator, it works fine. The build and publish processes didn’t show any errors either.

Comment: Could you provide detailed crash log information? In addition, you said that you uploaded a package. Does the package you uploaded support .NET 7?

Comment: I uploaded screenshots of exception logs to original post. As per your second question, I have no indication anywhere that .NET 7 isn’t supported. I was able to run it successfully in simulators and create the package so I believe .NET 7 is supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was setting the Flyout icon in `Styles.xaml` and this was the issue -- see below.

```
<Style TargetType="Shell" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
    <Setter Property="Shell.FlyoutIcon" Value="mymenuicon.png" />
</Style>
```

There's probably a way to set it in `Styles.xaml` and I'd appreciate it if someone can show me how to do that in the comments.

The fix for my problem was simply setting it in `AppShell` as follows:

```
<Shell
   x:Class="MyApp.AppShell"
   FlyoutIcon="mymenuicon.png">
  ...
</Shell>
```